# Rotation Matrix to Quaternion Expressions

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

I am wondering if someone could give some insight on how the four expressions are derived in this example. I was able to understand how to construct a quaternion to rotation matrix. However I am having some troubles seeing how they pulled the components out from the matrix. Here is the problem below.

[image: Rotation Matrix to Quaternion]

Comment: So what do you want to know?  Where the last four equations came from? How to solve the last four equations?  Something else?

Comment: Yea, pretty much I am just looking for how he was able to derive the 4 equations there. I am currently trying to use my Linear algebra tool set to see how this was done.

Comment: So the Matrix M is derived from taking a Rotation Matrix as an arbitrary Angle Axis representation. Then taking the W,X,Y,Z components of a Quaternion and doing trig substitution. Once you do that you get M. But I am a bit confused how you go backwards from that given just those matricies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get $(x,y,z,w)$ from the matrix, as they say, you can note that for example

$m_{00} = 1 -2y^2-2z^2$

$m_{11} = 1 -2x^2-2z^2$

$m_{22} = 1 -2x^2-2y^2$

So you can combine them as they suggest to get
$$1+m_{00}-m_{11}-m_{22} = 1 + (1 -2y^2 -2z^2) -1 +2x^2 + 2z^2 - 1 + 2x^2 + 2y^2$$ from which everything cancels except for $4x^2$ as they say.  Given that, you can evaluate $x$, and that enables you to substitute into the other equations and find $y,z$ and $w$.

Comment: Why did you choose to combine the diagonal values. In a sense, lets suppose you only had the matrix and was asked to produce the relationship for finding x y z and W what is your process?

Comment: I was able to solve for all of them. Thanks I see why you have to choose the diagonal because they all have common variables that you need to solve for